# Can't run SonarQube custom rules on pure XML code despite having SonarXML plugin?

Tags: xml, xpath, build, sonarqube

I am writing custom rules in XPATH to match XML (for "violating" XML code). SonarQube has the plugin SonarXML, which I have installed, but when I try building XML files (these are the files I want my XPATH rules to match on) they only partially build, meaning unsuccessful. So I add a basic C# file to get a successful build, which I do. Then when I check in Sonar after getting a successful build, my XML files are untouched. My custom rules didn't pick up the violations, even though I had SonarXML. Instead Sonar seemed to look only at the C# file, ignoring the XML files. What I want is Sonar to use its rules on the XML. I am aware that when it comes to custom rules, the code language (e.g. C#, Javascript) would get converted into an AST tree which the custom rules would then run on, but I need this to work on just XML code and I am having difficulties doing so. Am I doing something wrong with SonarXML? Or am I missing some obscure settings when building or on SonarQube? I'm building on Team Foundation Server and I believe I have the setup right, but who knows. I need a little nudge in the right direction.

My coworker says you can't test custom rules on pure XML files but isn't that the point of SonarXML? Please explain to me if I'm understanding wrong

Comment: Can you post the output of the scanner?

Comment: Did you review [this documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules+using+XPath) ? Notice the early mention about XML, where XPath can be used directly, without any notion of AST.

Comment: What's the result if you run the build locally instead of on TFS? The issue seems not related to TFS itself.

Comment: My coworkers have said not to post on StackOverflow because security reasons. Thank you, I will look into those places based on your comments